# Unable to Install MSSQL Server on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, ms-sql

I was following along with:

[Install SQL Server on Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-red-hat)

and I ran into the following error at the configuration portion:

```
Setting system administrator (SA) account password...
sqlservr: Error: Directory [/var/system/] could not be created.  Errno [2]
Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R) setup failed with error code 1.
Please check the setup log in /var/opt/mssql/log/setup-20170117-150619.log
for more information.
```

which obviously as stated I checked the logs but to my dismay:

```
[root@vps113437 log]# ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 mssql mssql 70 Jan 17 15:06 .
drwxrwx---. 5 mssql mssql 79 Jan 17 14:44 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 mssql mssql  0 Jan 17 14:51 setup-20170117-145127.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 mssql mssql  0 Jan 17 15:06 setup-20170117-150619.log
```

the log files are empty...

I have no idea where to start with this one... any ideas?

Things I have tried:

- creating /var/system (no change to the error)
- checking /var/log/audit/audit.log (also no entries)

Comment: Selinux maybe? Have you checked /var/log/audit.log?

Comment: Nothing was generated in /var/log/audit/audit.log. Thank you though!

Comment: What if you create /var/system yourself?

Comment: I wish, I tried that. Thank you for reminding me to add that to the question :)

Comment: I just installed it myself on a semi-clean CentOS 7 and everything just worked. Is that a clean CentOS or RHEL install you have?

Comment: What are the permissions on "/var/system"?

Answer (score 1):

I've just fixed this very same issue on a brand new Fedora 25 install, hosted on a chunky OVH server.

It turns out that I had a broken symlink in /var:

```
[tom@aaa ~]# ls -la /var
     lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    15 Feb  4 12:38 puppet -> /ovh/puppet/var
```

Deleting this file fixed everything :-)

I found this out after the error annoyed me so much, I installed strace, threw caution to the wind, and ran it through the failing command:

```
[root@aaa ~]# strace /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
               [.....]
stat("/var//lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/var//adm", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=6, ...}) = 0
stat("/var//puppet", 0x7ffe3b405a68)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x7f07eae42464, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7f07ea8ed1a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
write(2, "sqlservr: Error: Directory [/var"..., 75sqlservr: Error: Directory [/var/system/] could not be created.  Errno [2]
) = 75
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

That `-1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` made me suspicious, which is how I found the broken symlink, deleted it, and moved on.

I hope this helps someone else! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on my centos 7 vps. I ended up installing Docker and running the ms sql docker image.

EDIT: Thomas Buck's solution also worked for me and I would recommend going for that option. There's a weird link on OVH servers that somehow stops MS SQL from running...

Anyways, if you still want to run MS SQL with Docker, it's also quite easy.
To install Docker:

```
sudo yum -y install docker docker-registry
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl start docker.service
sudo systemctl status docker.service
```

Download and run MS SQL docker container:

```
sudo docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux
sudo mkdir /var/opt/mssql
sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=YourPassword' -p 1433:1433 -v /var/opt/mssql:/var/opt/mssql -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

More info:
Docker on CentOS 7: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-centos-7/
MS SQL Docker image: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-docker